# If $ 1 + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 6 = \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{d}}}}$ for integer $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, find $a+b+c+d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider the following equation:
>   $$ 1 + \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 6 = \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{d}}}}$$
>   where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are integers. Find $ a+b+c+d$

Comment: What have you tried? What's stopping you from squaring away?

Answer (score 5):

*Hint.* Notice that $\text{LHS}=(1+\sqrt 2)(1+\sqrt 3).$ Then square both sides as many times as necessary.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try?